# my kernel threads crash

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

First, look at my code (very simple, just to test)

```
struct task_struct *test_task;  

int test_func(void *arg)
{
    uint64_t cur = 0;   //current time 
    uint64_t last = 0;  //last time

    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        cur = get_cycle();
        if (cur - last > 2410000000)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "this time: %llu\n", cur);
            last = cur;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}    

void run_thread(void)
{
    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = 1;

    test_task = kthread_create(&test_func, NULL, "MY_test");
    kthread_bind(test_task, 2); //just use cpu 2
    sched_setscheduler(test_task, SCHED_RR, &param);
    wake_up_process(test_task);
    printk(KERN_INFO"OK, Kernel Thread : %s, Running\n", test_task->comm);
}

static int __init test_init(void)
{
    run_thread();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_exit(void)
{
    kthread_stop(test_task);
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);
```

These are all code, The problem occurs when I remove this module, the system would crash.
I think it should be a problem on my understanding of the core processes, please help gets advice, thank you!
Please forgive me for this chinese english....

Comment: get_cycle funciton just get current cpu cycle

Comment: Does your modue work without scheduler adjustment (`sched_setscheduler`)?

Comment: I need to keep my thread run forever，so

Comment: I don't force you to drop schedule-related part of your code completely, it is just debugging method for reduce search area: if your code works without this part, then the problem, possibly, with this part.

Comment: Only there will be problems in this part of the code, insert the module, and then remove the module, the system will crash

Comment: Crashing with given scenario is **observed behaviour**, resulted from some problem with your code. You need (and ask us for help) to find that problem. It is needed to localize problem. That's why I ask your to try your module without schedule-related part and check, whether crashing remains or not in this case.

Comment: Probably your thread is dead long before you called "rmmod".  Try doing "test_task = NULL" in function test_func() before returning 0. And check for it to be NULL in test_exit() function.

Comment: If `printk` follows a similar contract to `printf`, then `%llu` probably tells `printk` to expect an `unsigned long long` argument. This probably doesn't cause your problem, but you should fix it (by casting the argument to `(unsigned long long)`) anyway...

Comment: @Nithin     This is a while loop, will not quit early

Comment: @Seb the `uint64_t ` is `unsigned long long`, problem is not the `printk`

Comment: @Tsyvarev this code can be run directly, it is my problem can occur

Comment: _These are all code_ - you aren't seriously saying that your code has no `#include` and no `MODULE_…` macros, are you?